# Trouble with format of xml using PHP domDocument

Tags: php, xml

HI I am trying to create a XML file in php for the first time and it works but the layout isn't quite right I would like

```
<Markers>
  <marker></marker>
  <marker></marker>
   etc
</Markers>
```

instead I have

```
<markers>
 <marker>
    <marker>
       <marker>
       </marker>
    </marker>
   </marker>
 </markers>


<?PHP
  require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

  // Start XML file, create parent node
  $dom=new DOMDocument("1.0");
  $node=$dom->createElement("markers");
  $parnode=$dom->appendChild($node); 


  // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
  while (odbc_fetch_row($result)){
     $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
     $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
     $newnode->setAttribute("traffic",odbc_result($result,"TRAFFIC"));
     $newnode->setAttribute("latitude",odbc_result($result,"LATITUDE"));  
     $newnode->setAttribute("longitude",odbc_result($result,"LONGITUDE"));  
    } 

    echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I am populating from an ODBC connection.

I have tried looking around the net but haven't come across many examples on different layouts, thanks for any help or pointers in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce the problem. Have simplified to test without db data:

```
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom=new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node=$dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode=$dom->appendChild($node); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
   $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
   $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
   $newnode->setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
}   

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output (prettyfied):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
  <marker foo="bar"/>
  <marker foo="bar"/>
  <marker foo="bar"/>
</markers>
```

Can be tested [online](http://3v4l.org/DAYJo)

Comment: That's the problem I have the <markers> are nesting inside I would like <marker set my attributes></marker><marker foo=bar></marker> https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 following this tutorial and the example xml is what I am trying to achieve.